# Calling Google's Javascript API request.execute within request.execute

Tags: javascript, callback, google-api, google-api-js-client

What I'm trying to do is to get a list of calendars from google, and then get the list of events from each calendar. 
So basically I'm calling the events.list method within the callback function for the calendarList.list method. 
However, when debugging using Firebug, it appears that the callback function for the events.list method just doesn't get called at all.

```
var request2 = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
    "calendarId":calendarId
    });

request2.execute(function(response2) {
    resp2 = response2;
    findEvent();
    });
```

I can debug up to request2.execute, but function(response2) is never performed.
resp2 is a global variable, and all of this code is in a function called from the first request's callback. 
 A very similar code works perfectly for the first call, with a different global variable. 
I've tried removing either of the lines in the callback to no effect.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try putting a `console.log('inside callback); console.log(response2);` inside the callback function. Does 'inside callback' get printed in the log? If so, what is the value of response2?

Comment: Okay, this directed me towards the solution, although I'm not entirely sure what happened here yet: removing the firebug breakpoint solved the problem.